# Why is this if else statement showing an error ? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

why is this showing an error ?, I am trying to change the color of the unread chats with an if else condition but it is showing an error.
Error: Invalid constant value

[image]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the issue and what is chat in your case

Comment: When your code has a red underline you can hover your mouse over it to see what the error is

Answer (score 0):

Remove `const` from `BoxDecoration` because value`(chat) will get on runtime.

[image]

And if chat is nullable  try it like

```dart
color: chat!=null && chat!.unread? Colors.from(...): Colors.white,
```

Answer (score 0):

you have always to put the error with your question,
in your case, if you're working with null safety, then i think you have to change `chat.unread` to `chat!.unread`.
i cannot provide any more solution without knowing the exact error.

Comment: Invalid constant value. this is the error I am getting

Comment: then just remove const before BoxDecoration